# VS Code Files & Problems Tab Not Respecting .editorconfig

Tags: visual-studio-code, stylecop

I have installed the StyleCop analyser NuGet package and have overridden some rules in .editor config.

'dotnet build' respects these changes and has removed the errors.

However the Problems tab and code files in VS Code don't respect the changes.

[image: vs]

How can I get the files & Problems tab to respect .editorconfig?

Comment: Sorry for asking something obvious but I don't you mention it: have you installed and enabled the [EditorConfig extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EditorConfig.EditorConfig)?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes, I have.